# C++ Car Simulation

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue

C++ Data Structures using Queue, My code output is not correct, I am not sure what to change.

C++ using the stl Queue library, I am having trouble getting the correct output from my program. The wait time is not being displayed correctly and the start time of the wash is not being displayed correctly. This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <queue>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class averager {
private:
    int cnt;
    int sum;

public:
    averager() {
        cnt = 0;
        sum = 0;
    }
    void plus_next_number(int value) {
        cnt++;
        sum += value;
    }
    double average_time() {
        assert(cnt > 0);
        return (sum / cnt);
    }
    int how_many_cars() { return cnt; }
};

class Washmachine {
private:
    int time_for_wash;
    int time_left;

public:
    Washmachine(int n) {
        time_for_wash = n;
        time_left = 0;
    }

    bool is_busy() { return time_left > 0; }

    void startWashing() {
        assert(!is_busy());
        time_left = time_for_wash;
    }

    void one_second() {
        if(is_busy()) {
            --time_left;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    queue<int> waitQueue;
    int carArrival;
    averager cal;
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream arrivalrec;
    arrivalrec.open("arrival_time.txt");
    arrivalrec << "Car Number  "
               << "Arrival Time  "
               << "Car Wash Start Time  "
               << "Departure Time  "
               << "Wait Time  "
               << "Total Time  " << endl
               << endl;

    int maxWaitTime;   // maxWaitTime initially 0:00
    int totalWaitTime; // total time customers wait
    int endTime = 60;  // times for the simulation
    int totalServiceTime;
    int startTime;
    int carNum = 0;   // number of cars washed in study
    int washTime = 3; // fixed time for a wash in minutes
    int DeptTime;
    int TotalTime;
    int timeleft = 0;
    int waitTime;

    Washmachine carwashing(washTime);

    infile.open("input.txt");
    for(int startWash = 0; startWash <= endTime; startWash++) {
        infile >> startWash;
        waitQueue.push(startWash);
        if((!carwashing.is_busy()) && (!waitQueue.empty())) {
            carArrival = waitQueue.front();
            waitQueue.pop();
            cal.plus_next_number(startWash - carArrival);
            carwashing.startWashing();
        }
        carwashing.one_second();
        waitTime = startWash - carArrival;

        if(maxWaitTime < waitTime) maxWaitTime = waitTime;
        // add waiting time for customer to totalWaitTime.
        totalWaitTime += waitTime;
        totalServiceTime += washTime;

        startTime = startWash + waitTime;
        TotalTime = startWash + waitTime;

        DeptTime = startTime + washTime;
        // increment the number of customers served
        carNum++;
        // set washAvailable to false since equipment back in service

        // output the summary data for the simulation include number of cars
        // washed, average customer waiting time and pct of time wash operates

        arrivalrec << carNum << "              " << startWash
                   << "                   " << startTime << "                  "
                   << DeptTime << "              " << waitTime << "                "
                   << TotalTime << endl
                   << endl
                   << endl;
    }
    arrivalrec << "Maximum customer waiting time for a car wash is " << maxWaitTime
               << " minutes" << endl;
    arrivalrec << "Percentage of time car wash operates is  "
               << ((totalServiceTime / endTime) * 100.0) << '%' << endl;
    arrivalrec << "Number of customers remaining at " << endTime << " is "
               << waitQueue.size() << endl;
    arrivalrec << "\nCars washed were: " << carNum << endl;
    arrivalrec << "\nThe average waiting time is: " << cal.average_time() << endl;
    int car_denied = 0;
    while(!waitQueue.empty()) {
        waitQueue.pop();
        car_denied++;
    }
    arrivalrec << "\nThe number of denied cars is: " << car_denied << endl;
    arrivalrec << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The correct code output

[image]

My code output

[image]

Comment: 1) Note: whenever possible, copy-paste the text, instead of providing images of it. Your code output, could have been copy-pasted, for example. 2) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger, to see when the behavior, of your code, deviates from your expectations?

Comment: I have used the debugger, I'm not sure if it is because of the way my file is being read. I tried to read everything at once and then perform the functions but that just ruins the code as a whole giving a completely wrong output.

Comment: C: `<assert.h>`, C++ `<cassert>`.  C: `<stdlib.h>`, C++ `<cstdlib>`.

Comment: @MiaSheikh "_I have used the debugger_" **How** have you used the debugger? Did you step through your code line-by-line, while observing the values of all the variables, at each execution step, taking note, of when, exactly, the code does something, that you didn't expect? If you didn't: you didn't use the debugger. Related: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

The following code solves your task conform to the photographed description with two exceptions:

1. The average wait time isn't converted into minutes and seconds
2. The total car wash use time isn't reported

The rest works as specified:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include <queue>
#include <cstdlib>

constexpr auto SIMULATION_END_TIME = 80;
constexpr auto OPENING_END_TIME = 60;

using namespace std;

class averager {
private:
    int cnt;
    int sum;
public:
    averager(){
        cnt=0;
        sum=0;
    }
    void plus_next_number(int value)
    {
        cnt++;
        sum+=value;
    }
    double average_time()
    {
        assert(cnt>0);
        return (sum/static_cast<double>(cnt));
    }
    int how_many_cars()
    {
        return cnt;
    }
};

class Washmachine {
private:
    int time_for_wash;
    int time_left;
public:
    Washmachine(int n) {
        time_for_wash = n;
        time_left = 0;

    }

    bool is_busy() {
        return (time_left > 0);
    }

    void startWashing() {
        if(!is_busy()) {
            time_left = time_for_wash;
        }

    }

    void one_second(){
        if(is_busy()) {
            --time_left;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    queue<int> waitQueue;
    int carArrival = 0;
    averager cal;
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream arrivalrec;
    arrivalrec.open("arrival_time.txt");
    arrivalrec << "Start of Simulation" << endl;
    arrivalrec << "Car\t\tArrival\tCar Wash\tDeparture\tWait\tTotal" << endl;
    arrivalrec << "Number\tTime\tStart Time\tTime\t\tTime\tTime" << endl;
    arrivalrec << "------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

    int maxWaitTime = 0;   // maxWaitTime initially 0:00
    int totalWaitTime = 0;           // total time customers wait
    int totalServiceTime = 0;
    int startTime = 0;
    int carNum = 0;         // number of cars washed in study
    int washTime = 3;                       // fixed time for a wash in minutes
    int DeptTime = 0;
    int TotalTime = 0;
    int timeleft=0;
    int waitTime=0;
    int temp;
    int sw;
    int runTime;
    Washmachine carwashing(washTime);



    infile.open("input.txt");
    infile >> temp;
    carNum = 1;

    for (runTime=1;runTime<=SIMULATION_END_TIME;runTime++){

        if (runTime == temp) {
            waitQueue.push(temp);
            infile >> temp;
        }
        if((runTime <= OPENING_END_TIME)&&(!carwashing.is_busy())&&(!waitQueue.empty())) {
            carArrival=waitQueue.front();
            waitQueue.pop();
            startTime = runTime;
            waitTime=startTime-carArrival;
            totalWaitTime += waitTime;
            TotalTime = washTime + waitTime;
            if (maxWaitTime < waitTime)
                maxWaitTime = waitTime;
            cal.plus_next_number(startTime-carArrival);
            carwashing.startWashing();
        }
        else
        {
            waitTime++;
        }
        if (carwashing.is_busy())
            carwashing.one_second();

        if ((!carwashing.is_busy())&&(startTime >= DeptTime)) {
            DeptTime = startTime + washTime;
            totalServiceTime += washTime;
            arrivalrec << carNum << "\t\t" << carArrival << "\t\t" << startTime
                << "\t\t\t" << DeptTime << "\t\t\t" <<
                waitTime << "\t\t" << TotalTime << endl;
            carNum++;
        }
    }
    int car_denied = 0;
    while (!waitQueue.empty())
    {
        arrivalrec << carNum << "\t\t" << waitQueue.front() << "\tCar arrived after closing time and was not served." << endl;
        waitQueue.pop();
        car_denied++;
        carNum++;
    }
    arrivalrec << "End of Simulation" << endl << endl;
    arrivalrec << "Statistics:" << endl;
    arrivalrec << "\tTotal wait time: " << totalWaitTime << " minutes" << endl;
    arrivalrec << "\tMaximum customer waiting time for a car wash is "
                << maxWaitTime << " minutes" << endl;
    arrivalrec << "\tPercentage of time car wash operates is "
                << ((totalServiceTime / static_cast<double>(OPENING_END_TIME)) * 100.0)
                << " %" << endl;
    arrivalrec<<"\tCars washed were: "<<carNum - car_denied - 1<<endl;
    arrivalrec<<"\tThe average waiting time is: "<<cal.average_time()<<endl; // TODO: Convert time to minutes and seconds
    arrivalrec<<"\tThe number of denied cars is:"<<car_denied<<endl;
    arrivalrec<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output of `arrival_time.txt` file is:

```
Start of Simulation
Car     Arrival Car Wash    Departure   Wait    Total
Number  Time    Start Time  Time        Time    Time
------------------------------------------------------------
1       1       1           4           2       3
2       2       4           7           4       5
3       4       7           10          5       6
4       10      10          13          2       3
5       13      13          16          2       3
6       15      16          19          3       4
7       16      19          22          5       6
8       75  Car arrived after closing time and was not served.
End of Simulation

Statistics:
    Total wait time: 9 minutes
    Maximum customer waiting time for a car wash is 3 minutes
    Percentage of time car wash operates is 35 %
    Cars washed were: 7
    The average waiting time is: 1.28571
    The number of denied cars is:1
```

Please check the code with your one and accept this answer if it fits to your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

untitled.cc:7:1: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
constexpr auto SIMULATION_END_TIME = 80;
^
untitled.cc:7:11: error: expected unqualified-id
constexpr auto SIMULATION_END_TIME = 80;
          ^
untitled.cc:8:1: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
constexpr auto OPENING_END_TIME = 60;
^
untitled.cc:8:11: error: expected unqualified-id
constexpr auto OPENING_END_TIME = 60;
          ^
untitled.cc:99:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'SIMULATION_END_TIME'
    for (runTime=1;runTime<=SIMULATION_END_TIME;runTime++){
                            ^
untitled.cc:105:24: error: use of undeclared identifier 'OPENING_END_TIME'
        if((runTime <= OPENING_END_TIME)&&(!carwashing.is_busy())&&(!waitQueue.empty())) {
                       ^
untitled.cc:147:61: error: use of undeclared identifier 'OPENING_END_TIME'
                << ((totalServiceTime / static_cast(OPENING_END_TIME)) * 100.0)
                                                            ^
7 errors generated.